# None response from youtube api while deleting videos

Tags: python, django, youtube-api, gdata

i am trying to delete the youtube video from my webapp, using python client library gdata

here is what i am trying

```
..setting all parameters for yt_service

yt_service.ProgrammaticLogin()
entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id= video_id)
```

where entry object has the entire youtube video in xml format and also the login is working fine.

but when i try this

```
response = yt_service.DeleteVideoEntry(entry)
```

the response is None,

i am not even able to debug, please try and help if anybody has used this already.

thanks.

Comment: how does client.yt_service.DeleteVideoEntry() differ from yt_service.DeleteVideoEntry()?

Comment: Hi @skzryzg thanks for the reply, that was a mistake i edited my question.

Comment: I wonder if this is similar to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14199745/unable-to-delete-videos-with-the-youtube-data-api